# Reduce space between 2 specific ticks on a chart.js Y axis

Tags: chart.js

I have a line graph in chart.js where my data will never be in a specific range so I want to remove that section from the Y axis while preserving the natural step size of the rest of the data.

For example, my data can be anything between 1 to 100, but will never be between 50 and 60. So I want my Y axis to automatically space it out to use the entire graph even if the data is just between 30-40, but if it spans between 40-80 I want the 50-60 range to be completely missing. Meaning the ticks go from 40, 45, 50, 60, 65, etc without having a big blank white space where the 55 was. I'm using the below callback to remove the tick, but I can't seem to remove the space.

```
callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    if (value !== 55) {
                        return value;
                      }
                      return '';
                    }
                }
```

I wasn't able to find a good way to remove space in the middle, only can alter the min and max.